# Trim the excess of an object in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, shapes, resize, cutter

I have a figure formed by two objects like this:

[image]

I want to remove the excess of the red object in Inkscape, to get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do it, and probably more than those I've listed here below.

Copy and Paste in Place the blue rectangle, select the new blue rectangle and the red ellipse. Click *Object > Clip > Set.*

or

Select both rectangle and ellipse, click *Path > Division*, select the ellipse inside, and change the fill colour back to red.

Comment: Or duplicate the blue object, shift- click both the red ellipse and the blue object on top and do an "Intersection"? I don't think he wants to cut up the blue rectangle, just cut the excess off the red ellipse.