# Remove excess portions from an object in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

[I know, I used the same title from this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/101914/trim-the-excess-of-an-object-in-inkscape/101915#101915?newreg=f3d67c99390b4a57869082d620b5fc48), but I want to actually remove the trimmed objects. It seems the trimmed objects are still in the image, when I go to laser-cut the graphic, the trimmed components show up, and register as out of bounds.
[image]

Here is the image as I see it in Inkscape:
[image]

I would like the hexagons I trimmed out to not be part of the image at all. How do I do that in inkscape?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Perhaps you are trying to overthink this. Can't you simply delete the hexagons you don't want?  Have you tried to do this?

Comment: I want the hexagons, well I want the image as it appears in inkscape. I'm no master of inkscape that is certain. I thought the trimmed term, meant deleted, that was evidently not the case. maybe I can manipulate the shape more.

Comment: @joh - it depends how you are doing the trimming.. You could use clipping mask which won't delete the shapes, or you could use a boolean operation which will allow you to actually delete parts.

Comment: can you give a bit more detail on how to do that? I tried breaking the vectors apart, and deleting portions that are out of bounds, but that could be tedious for more complex drawings.

Comment: Vector drawing applications dont usually do this easily. Reason being that theyoperate on the assumption that lines are stroked things. if you now cut them the cut shape does nolonger represent the same shape, So for the designed usecase doing this is against the core purpose of the application. Path of least suprise to users. But laser cutters assume the source document has a CAD application kind of mentality. Now cad applications think a line is juat a line so cutting it has no side effects and they usually do this easily. So its more about managing expectations than anything

Comment: This is a good example of a situation where concepts do not translate very well between professions. For a graphic designer its given that a line and a stroked line is the same thing. While a person attempting to use a vector application as a replacement for a CAM application will disagre very vocally as tese things really produce different results.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine the black lines should be cut along the edge which is now the red rectangle and the parts outside the edge should simply vanish without causing anything else (= no new lines, no hidden parts, nothing vanishes splits nor moves inside the edge).

[image]

Unfortunately original colors will be lost if there's more than one.

The first steps are the same as suggested in an earlier answer: Combine the black curves (Path > Combine), send them to back and duplicate the rectangle. If there's many overlapping curves you can select all and remove the rectangle from the selection by holding the shift. Do it before duplicating the rectangle.

Select the combined path and one of the rectangles. Apply Path > Cut Path. The selected rectangle vanishes:

[image]

Every black line below the red line is cut. You can select easily the unwanted parts and press DEL. Here's the result. The duplicate rectangle is moved aside and one of the closed curves is selected to show it's still one piece:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127243/discussion-on-answer-by-user287001-remove-trimed-portions-from-the-excess-of-an).

Answer (score 2):

1. Assuming the hexagons are all separate objects, select all of them and do *Path > Combine*.  This will make a combined/compound path. Essentially, this will turn them all into one path (i.e. one object). If the hexagons are already a combined path, skip this step.

[image]

2. Enable snapping to the page boundary, and snapping to cusp nodes, then draw a rectangle same size as the page. The rectangle should snap to the page corners.
3. Select the hexagons' combined path, and the rectangle, and do *Path > Intersection*. This is one of Inkscape's boolean operations, and basically what it does is that it consumes/removes everything outside of the areas that intersect.

[image]